# Libgdx cant draw text out on my screen

Tags: android, text, fonts, draw, libgdx

Im trying to get a score function on my game to show how much points you got but cant get it to work.

```
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/whitefont.fnt"),
             Gdx.files.internal("data/whitefont_0.png"), false);
```

to get my font.

```
batch.begin();
//render backgrounds and models
font.draw(batch, textToDisplay, 20, 1);
    System.out.println(textToDisplay);
batch.end();
```

Trying to draw the text. The log shows that the text prints but there is nothing on the screen.

I dont get anything out on that position and my font is white so it should work on my black background. Cant find the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253448/draw-string-with-bitmapfont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing the Y value, like say:

```
font.draw(batch, textToDisplay, 20, 40);
```

Remember that (0,0) is on left bottom of the window (or screen, in case of full-screen).

Comment: Yea thanks, It was a combination of the font and the camera. My camera were so much zoomed in, the text were drawed but under the camera. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generate the fnt and png files from hiero again.
It seems they aren't from the same. For example the name, the png one has _0 suffix, suspicious.